# How to the measure the rendering difference after putting all JS from <head> to Bottom of the page?

Tags: javascript, performance, web-applications, google-chrome-devtools

I have a website where there are multiple Javascript files inside `<head>` and it's a known practice for better performance to keep all possible Javascript to bottom of the page, just before the closing body tag `</body>`.

How can I measure that how much benefit will be there in page rendering/performance if I move JS to bottom.

Comment: I think it's more of a perceived difference than anything else. The user will see the page content faster because the page content will be parsed before the browser blocks to load/execute the javascript (mostly the load part, since generally code in the head is wrapped in an onload or on dom ready handler, so the code doesn't actually execute until later other than the event binding itself.)

Comment: Basically, if you calculate how long it takes all of your javascript to load, that's how much faster the user will see the rendered page if you moved the js to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Since your goal is to measure how long it takes you browser to parse all scripts referenced by your `<script src="..."></script>` tags, you can use `console.time` in your page (this change does not affect the `DOMContentLoaded` event timing):

```
<script>console.time("foo");</script>
<script src="script1.js"></script>
...
<script src="scriptN.js"></script>
<script>console.timeEnd("foo");</script>
```

and then take a look at the console.